# interlocked operation on unanligned data

Tags: thread-safety, alignment, atomic, interlocked, multiprocessor

The win32 interlocked functions provide a mecanism for atomic operation on data. They are supposed to be thread-safe and multiprocessor-safe.

What happen if the data is not aligned? the interlocked operations are still atomic?
Ex.: incrementing a integer that is not aligned.

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read most of the Interlocked API functions, there are remarks that specify something along the lines of:

"The variable pointed to by the Addend parameter must be aligned on a 32-bit boundary; otherwise, this function will behave unpredictably on multiprocessor x86 systems and any non-x86 systems. See _aligned_malloc."

For an example, see this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614(VS.85).aspx).

This basically says you need to align your data for proper results, using _aligned_malloc.